# Match 2 or more uppercase characters in entire string

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to create a pattern in PHP that matches **2 or more** upper case characters in a string.

I've tried the following, but it only matches 2 or more upper case characters in a row, not the entire string:

`preg_match('/[A-Z]{2,}/', $string);`

For example, the string "aBcDe" or "Red Apple" should return true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all you need to do is identify that a string contains at least 2 uppercase characters then you can use the following:

```
[A-Z].*?[A-Z]
```

Try it [here](https://regex101.com/r/nG7zF6/1).

If you need to identify the specific uppercase characters in the string then things get more complicated.

UPDATE: As Lucas mentioned, you need a different regex if you want unicode support.

```
\p{Lu}.*?\p{Lu}
```

Comment: I do like yours though, because unicode!  This one should suffice though.

Comment: `\p{Lu}.*?\p{Lu}`  :-)

Answer (score 3):

You just have to allow other characters between your uppercase letters:

```
^(?:.*?\p{Lu}){2}
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/gA7fG2/1)

I used `\p{Lu}` here to include Unicode characters as well. If you don't want that just use `[A-Z]` instead like you did in your pattern.

This simply means:

- `^` from the start of the pattern
- `(?:` group:

  - `.*?` match anything, but as few chars as possible
  - `\p{Lu}` match an uppercase letter
- `){2}` ... two times

Answer (score 0):

If you need to match the whole line/string that has at least 2 upper case letters, you can also use

`^(?=(?:.*[A-Z]){2}).+$`

[Demo here](https://regex101.com/r/aD8tE9/2).

Answer (score 0):

```
^.*[A-Z].*[A-Z].*$
```

A simple pattern stating the same would do.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/pT4tM5/23

Answer (score 0):

```
[A-Z].*[A-Z]
```

is about as simple as it gets - match an uppercase followed by anything repeated any number of times followed by any other uppercase letter.

Comment: .* is greedy and might lead to unwanted matching.

Comment: Um, who cares? He wants to know if there are 2 upper-case letters, right?

Comment: This will lead to unwanted *backtracking*, thus making the match slower. Making the quantifier ungreedy is an optimization.

Comment: I find in about 999 out of 1000 times regex is so fast it is not the bottleneck and optimization efforts should be focused on other areas of the code. Having said that, making it non-greedy will be (ever-so-slightly-and-probably negligibly) faster. You're right.

Comment: I'd say it's more about good habits more than anything else.  If you get into the habit of using the greedy match (.*) it can catch you out badly.